# android gmail app like List View with 4 icon in a icon

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

how can i generate icon using 4 diffrent icons like gmail app have icon with text programmatically, i have spend couple of hours to generate it with [TextDrawable](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawabl) but would not able to modify it to use with images

here is the screenshot what i am trying to achive

[image]

the numbers 1,2 etc will be replaced with other small images.
any hint or help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You can use a gridview with 2 columns, 2 rows

Comment: thanks @its-tomweber but using gridview each time i have to reinitialize gridview adapter  for every row of listview is it good technique ??

Comment: Sorry i mean gridlayout. You can use it like a linearlayout in the xml directly. No need for an adapter. It's similiar to the answer below

Comment: Yes its good to use gridlayout instead of the two linears thanks

Comment: its also easier to use in the source code if you need it.

Comment: i provided my answer. Feel free to rate it ;) if you have any further questions, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my layout construction which generate this image:

[image]

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffacacac"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#ffff2983"
                android:src="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#ffa1ff55"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_set_as" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#ff5bffec"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#ff4d4eff"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_month" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: U can use a gridlayout instead of the two linears

Comment: This variant is better. Cause u don`t need an adapter.

Comment: You don't need an adapter for gridlayout as well. Only for gridview. That are two different classes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a gridlayout with 2 columns and 2 rows as well. You can fill it with your imageviews right in your xml layout file and can manipulate it in your activity/fragment code or even more in your adapter/viewholder